# Pandas read_sql incorrectly reading my_sql date function

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I'm currently using SQLAlchemy to download data from a MySQL database into Pandas. The timestamp data in the database is in string form, so I am using the MySQL function str_to_date to convert this into a date value before reading it into Pandas. However, when doing this, I noticed that Pandas was not interpreting this value correctly.

Here is a simplified example that I constructed describing the problem.

```
import sqlalchemy as sqla
import pandas as pd

# Connect to database
settings = {'host': '127.0.0.1', 'user': 'root', 'passwd': 'password', 'db': 'data'}
connection_str = "mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}".format(settings['user'], settings['passwd'],
                                                      settings['host'], settings['db'])
engine = sqla.create_engine(connection_str)
con = engine.connect()

# Build query
sql_string = sqla.text("SELECT str_to_date('2021-04-05', '%Y-%m-%d') AS date;")

# Read data
dataframe = pd.read_sql(sql_string, con)
raw_value = con.execute(sql_string).fetchone()
con.close()
```

Next, if I print the above two values, I see the following results.

```
> print(dataframe)

   date
0  None

> print(raw_value)

(datetime.date(2021, 4, 5),)
```

As you can see, the data is correctly pulled into python as a datetime.date object if I use a cursor to fetch it. However, if I attempt to use Pandas's read_sql function to fetch the data it shows up as a None value instead. Why is this the case, and can I do something on my end to fix this issue with Pandas? (For example, maybe I can modify my query a bit to get the result I want?)

If it helps, I am currently running Python 3.7.9. In terms of my installed packages: Pandas is on version 1.1.3, sqlalchemy is version 1.3.20, pymysql is version 1.0.2. The MySQL database that I am pulling this data from is very old, and is running on version 5.7.20.

Comment: And what if you specify parse_dates argument for read_sql()? Try removing str_to_date() from query and setting parse_dates={'date': '%Y-%m-%d'}

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue using MySQL server 5.6.13 (older than 5.7.20) and current versions of pandas, SQLAlchemy, and PyMySQL. [This code](https://pastebin.com/7AXfte0t) works fine for me.